# Match Strings of 2 dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame:

Df1:

Original df has 1000+ Name

```
   Id    Name
    1     Paper
    2     Paper Bag
    3     Scissors
    4     Mat
    5     Cat
    6     Good Cat
```

2nd Df:

Original df has 1000+ Item_Name

```
Item_ID   Item_Name
1         Paper Bag
2         wallpaper
3         paper
4         cat cage
5         good cat
```

Expected Output:

```
Id Name         Item_ID
1  Paper         1,2,3
2  Paper Bag     1,2,3
3  Scissors      NA 
4  Mat           NA 
5  Cat           4,5
6  Good Cat           4,5
```

**My Code:**

```
def matcher(x):
    res = df2.loc[df2['Item_Name'].str.contains(x, regex=False, case=False), 'Item_ID']
    return ','.join(res.astype(str))

df1['Item_ID'] = df1['Name'].apply(matcher)
```

**Current Challenges**

`str.contains` work when name has Paper and Item_Name has Paper Bag but it doesn't work other way around. So, it my example it work for row 1,3,4,5 for `df1` but not for row 2 & 6. So, it will **not** map **row 2 of df1 with row 3 of df2**

**Ask**

So, if you can help me in modifying the code so that it can help in matching otherway round also

Comment: Why would it work the other way around?  "Paper Bag" is not in "Paper"

Comment: So all I want is partial matching...any of the two or three words match with the given word

Comment: It sounds like your problem is breaking down the compound words and running comparisons against each then

Comment: Yes!!Only for compound words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your custom `matcher` function and use `apply()`:

```
def matcher(query):

    matches = [i['Item_ID'] for i in df2[['Item_ID','Name']].to_dict('records') if any(q in i['Name'].lower() for q in query.lower().split())]
    if matches:
        return ','.join(map(str, matches))
    else:
        return 'NA'

df1['Item_ID'] = df1['Name'].apply(matcher)
```

Returns:

```
   Id       Name Item_ID
0   1      Paper   1,2,3
1   2  Paper Bag   1,2,3
2   3   Scissors      NA
3   4        Mat      NA
4   5        Cat     4,5
5   6   Good Cat     4,5
```

Explanation:

We are using `apply()` to apply our custom `matcher()` function to each row value of your `df1['Name']` column. In our `matcher()` function, we are converting `df2` into a dictionary with the `Item_ID` as the keys and the `Name` as the values. We then can check if our current row value `query` is present in `any()` of the `Name` values from `df1` (converted to lowercase via `lower()`), and if so, then we can add the `Item_ID` to a list to be returned.

Comment: I am runnin your code on my df...give me some time. Also, if you give comments on what part of code is doing what..it will be really helpful

Comment: I've added some commentary to my answer.

Comment: Just 1 more query..if I need to map two columns instead of one..i.e. `Item_Id` and one more column `Material_Id`. Is their any way we can tweak the code and do it...currently I am running the same function two times by changing column name

Comment: Go ahead and post that as a separate question and either I or someone else can help you work through it.